# Pressing Enter Refreshing Page Instead of Executing Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to execute a Javascript function after the user enters data in a text field and then presses enter. But when pressing enter it refreshes the page instead. Here is my code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/distance.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&libraries=geometry&sensor=true">
    </script>
</head>


<form action="distance_calc_sort_db.php">
    Patient Zip Code at Minimum
    <input type="text" id="address1" name="address1" value="" size="15" autofocus>
    <input type="button" id="nsgsearchbutton" name="find" value="search" onclick="showLocationLoop()">
    <input type="submit" name="find0" value="clear">
</form>

<script>
    function showLocationLoop() {
        alert("In showLocationLoop");
        geocoder.geocode({'address': document.getElementById("address1").value}, function (response, status) {
                if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    alert("Please enter patient's zip code!");
                }
                else {
                    /***** 1 */
            <?php   $loop_count = 1;
                    foreach ($locations_array as $location_name => $location_address) { ?>
                        var location1 = {LatLng: response[0].geometry.location, address: response[0].formatted_address};
                    <?php   if ($loop_count==1) { ?>
                                createPoint(location1.address,'red');
                    <?php } ?>
                        geocoder.geocode({'address': '<?php echo $location_address ?>'}, function (response,status) {
                            if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                                alert("Sorry, we were unable to geocode the second address due to " + status);
                            }
                            else {
                                setTimeout(function() {
                                    var location2 = {LatLng: response[0].geometry.location, address: response[0].formatted_address};
                                    try {
                                        var glatlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(location1.LatLng.lat(), location1.LatLng.lng());
                                        var glatlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(location2.LatLng.lat(), location2.LatLng.lng());
                                        // (y meters * 1.0936) / 1760 ===> miles
                                        var distancemeters = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(glatlng1, glatlng2);
                                        var distancemiles = ((distancemeters * 1.0936) / 1760).toFixed(1);
                                        var distancekm = (distancemeters / 1000).toFixed(1);
                                <?php   if ($loop_count==1) { ?>
                                            document.getElementById('results1').innerHTML = "<strong><font color='red'>Patient's Address: </strong>" + location1.address + "</font>";
                                <?php   } ?>
                                        document.getElementById('results' + '<?php echo $loop_count+1 ?>' + '_1').innerHTML = "<?php echo $location_name ?>";
                                        document.getElementById('results' + '<?php echo $loop_count+1 ?>' + '_2').innerHTML = distancemiles + " miles";
                                        setTimeout(function() {
                                            createPoint(location2.address,'green');
                                        }, <?php echo $loop_count * 500 ?>/*2500 for 6 locations*/);
                                <?php   // sort table after all geocoding is complete
                                        if ($loop_count==count($locations_array)) { ?>
                                            $(document).ready(function() {
                                                //setTimeout(function(){ $("#myTable").tablesorter({sortList: [ [1,0]]});  }, 5000);
                                                // tablesorter to sort on the second column in ascending order http://tablesorter.com/docs/
                                                $("#myTable").tablesorter({sortList: [ [1,0] ]});
                                            });
                                <?php   } ?>
                                    }
                                    catch (error) {
                                        alert(error);
                                    }
                                }, <?php echo $loop_count * 600; ?>/*2000 for 6 locations*/);
                            }
                        });
            <?php       $loop_count++;
                    } ?>
                }
            });
        }
</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#address1').keypress(function(e){
          if(e.keyCode==13) {
            $('#nsgsearchbutton').click();
            //alert("PRESSED test Search!!! Wooohhhooo!!!");
          }
        });
    });
</script>
```

For some weird reason I get the alert message displaying BUT it does not run the geocoding code in the showLocationLoop() function, instead it refreshes the page. Please help.

Comment: Separate your PHP can JavaScript code. There is no reason to mix these languages - unless you're in obfuscation challenge.

Comment: Some of us are multilingual, as that is a valuable skill to have ;-)

Comment: As a webdeveloper you have to be multilingual but pick your battles. Right now it's as if you're telling a story and you're changing de idioma en el medio de una frase.

Comment: We all get to choose how we want to be multilingual perche io devo finire quest progetto per mio lavoro ;-)

Answer (score 0):

When you press enter inside a `form` tag, it will do submit for form. You can use `onsubmit` attribute for `form` tag and call your JavaScript function from there. After calling your function write `return false`, that will tell form to not submit, so page won't be refreshed.

Comment: Thank @Epsilon :-) I removed the form tags and changed the buttons section to this: `Patient Zip Code at Minimum
   <input type="text" id="address1" name="address1" value="" size="15" autofocus>
   <input type="button" id="nsgsearchbutton" name="find" value="search" onclick="showLocationLoop()">
   <input type="button" name="find0" value="clear" onclick="mReloadPage()"> <script>
  function myReloadPage(){
   location.reload(true);
  }
 </script>` and I added a JavaScript function reload to clear the page. Thanks again! :-)